# How to solve app.json while creating new application in vue-native

Tags: react-native, vue.js, expo, vue-native

I was try to init a new app in VueJS but it keeps complaining about app.json. I got the following error message.

```
apps vue-native init tadaapp
Using globally installed expo-cli 3.4.0

Creating Vue Native project tadaapp

⠋ Creating project with expo-cli
✔ Please enter a few initial configuration values.
  Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/ · 100% completed
Extracting project files...
Customizing project...
Can't read JSON file: /Users/cherhan/Documents/apps/tadaapp/app.json
└─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cherhan/Documents/apps/tadaapp/app.json'
✔ Created project with expo-cli

⠋ Installing Vue Native dependencies
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN vue-native-helper@0.1.4 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-native-core@0.1.4 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN blank@0.1.22 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

+ vue-native-helper@0.1.4
+ vue-native-core@0.1.4
added 2 packages from 1 contributor and audited 2 packages in 1.074s
found 0 vulnerabilities
✔ Installed Vue Native dependencies

⠋ Installing Vue Native devDependencies

> core-js@2.6.10 postinstall /Users/cherhan/Documents/apps/tadaapp/node_modules/core-js
> node postinstall || echo "ignore"

npm WARN vue-native-core@0.1.4 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-native-helper@0.1.4 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-native-scripts@0.1.4 requires a peer of react-native@^0.59.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-native-scripts@0.1.4 requires a peer of metro@^0.51.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-native-scripts@0.1.4 requires a peer of metro-bundler@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-native-scripts@0.1.4 requires a peer of metro-react-native-babel-transformer@^0.51.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN blank@0.1.22 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

+ @babel/core@7.6.4
+ vue-native-scripts@0.1.4
added 148 packages from 86 contributors and audited 563 packages in 4.348s
found 0 vulnerabilities
✔ Installed Vue Native devDependencies

(node:52272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
    at setupVueNativeApp (/Users/cherhan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-native-cli/src/index.js:295:35)
    at createExpoProject (/Users/cherhan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-native-cli/src/index.js:124:9)
    at init (/Users/cherhan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-native-cli/src/index.js:101:5)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/cherhan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-native-cli/src/index.js:69:7)
    at Command.listener (/Users/cherhan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Command.parseArgs (/Users/cherhan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/Users/cherhan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
(node:52272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:52272) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```